# ms08_067_netapi not performing as expected on Windows XP SP1/SP3

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter, windows-xp

I tried the exploit with meterpreter reverse tcp on both SP1/SP3 machines and both returned a statement of `exploit completed but no session was created`. Both machines have firewall off. I want to have my first meterpreter session opened to experiment with this. BTW, these are virtual machines.

XP SP3 RESULT:

```
Started reverse TCP handler on [LHOST]:4444
Automatically detecting your target 
Fingerprint: Windows XP SP3 English (AlwaysOn NX)
Selected Target: Windows XP SP3 English (AlwaysOn NX)
Attempting to trigger the vulnerability 
Exploit completed, but no session was created
```

Comment: Please provide a list of all of the commands you executed along with a netstat or nmap of the Windows machine.

Comment: confirm the networking between the attacker and target - can you ping? Can you see the exploit occurring on the target? What do the packet traces say?

Comment: Run nmap -p 445 --script smb-check-vulns <IP> and look at the results. The machine should be vulnerable only then the exploit will work.

Comment: I can ping with quite some speed

Comment: Nmap scan doesn't work and it shows the default list of commands from nmap

Comment: I tried nmap with success after disabling the XP firewall, alas the session is still not being created in Metasploit

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons for this exploit to fail, in short:

- The target is patched.
- 'Not supported language' error from the target.
- The payload can't execute correctly.
- Networking errors 'reverse connection through NAT'.

From experience with the same issue, I recommend to do the following:

- Try not to use VMs.
- Try another payloads, away from reverse connections.
- Try other versions of Windows XP.
- Change system languages 'sometime it works!'

After all, since it says `Exploit completed, but no session was created` that means something is preventing the reverse connection, mostly the system is patched.

Comment: Is it possible that kali is blocking the reverse connection port 4444

Comment: SP 1 Result shows that it  can't detect the language

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I had an actual need to get the admin password from my lab xp in order to update a guitar pedal (wouldn't update on windows 10 so I needed xp). It's been a few years since I worked on this XP/exploit but the reverse tcp used to work. I am using an updated version of Kali now and the reverse doesn't work. I used the following to get it to work correctly

`set payload windows/meterpreter/bind_tcp`